# New Installer vs Old Installer

Tags: release-odin, live-installation

Is there a reason for not including some items in the old installer to the new one?

For example, in the old installer you can set the hostname, clock, user, etc... This can be set in the command line, but it took me quite some time of googling.

Just genuinely curius...

Answer (score 0):

It was probably to simplify the installation process. And by the way, you can configure all of those settings in the settings menu after the first login, although that might be cumbersome for some.